# Rails AntiPatterns book - Doubts on composition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, composition, anti-patterns

I'm reading the [Rails AntiPatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814) book, which I'm enjoying a lot.  At one point, the author talks about the goodness of composition and it gives an example where an **Order** class gives the responsibility of conversion (to other formats) to another class, called **OrderConverter**. The classes are defined as:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    def converter
        OrderConverter.new(self)
    end
end

class OrderConverter
    attr_reader :order
    def initialize(order)
        @order = order
    end
    def to_xml
        # ...
    end
    def to_json
        # ...
    end
    ...
end
```

And then the author says: "*In this way, you give the conversion methods their own home, inside a separate and easily testable class. Exporting the PDF version of an order is now just a matter of call-ing the following:*"

```
@order.converter.to_pdf
```

Regarding to this, my questions are:

- Why do you think that order object is preceded by an @? Shouldn't it be created as:

  order = Order.new

And then convert by doing:

```
order.converter.to_pdf
```

- Why is the `attr_reader :order` line needed in the OrderConverter? It's so we can access the order from an **OrderConverter** object? Is it needed to be able to do 
  `order.converter.to_pdf` ? We could do that without that **attr_reader** right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of `Order` is passed to the `initialize` method and stored as an instance variable (using the @ syntax : `@order`). This way, this variable can be accessed from other methods in the converter (the variable has the instance scope) :

```
class OrderConverter
  def to_pdf
    @order.items.each do |item|
       # Write the order items to the PDF
    end
  end
end
```

The attr_reader is not strictly required, but is a convenient way to access the Order object from other methods :

```
class OrderConverter
  def to_pdf
    order.items.each do |item|
       # Write the order items to the PDF
    end
  end
end
```

It will also allow you to get the reference to the order out of any converter instance :

```
converter.order
```

Comment: Jeff, I believe that even without doing attr_reader we could access the Order object from other methods (inside the same class) right? I believe it's just useful to get the order from any converter instance.

Comment: Sure, that why I added that from the inside of the converter, the `attr_reader` would simply be a convenience accessor.

But without `attr_accessor :order`, any call to `converter.order` would raise a "NoMethodError". The reference to the order would not be accessible outside this particular instance , as the instance variables have... the instance scope.

Comment: Sorry, too much typos/edits on the previous comment : read `attr_reader` (read-only), not `attr_accessor` (read-write).

Answer (score 2):

The `@` on the front of the variable makes it an instance variable. If it wasn't there the variable would just be a local variable.  I'm guessing that since this is a book about Rails, it's assuming that this code would be in a controller.  Variables that controllers want to share across methods or expose in their views need to be instance variables.  If this is the case `@order` was probably created either via parameters from a request or with values pulled from the database.

This probably isn't that significant though, both his example and your example work - I think the author was just showing how a call to the `OrderConverter` would look, and ignored how the `Order` object got created.

`attr_reader :order` creates a "getter" method for the `@order` instance variable in `OrderConverter` - it's not needed for `to_pdf` - it would be used to get the `Order` back out of the `OrderConverter` via `converter.order`.  I don't see any need to have this in the code you've given so far, but maybe there's some need for it later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish I could give two accepted answers, both of them helped me a lot to clarify this concept.